# Linux command line regex processing tool for easy multiline operations?

Tags: regex, command-line

I only recently started to learn regex. My first incursion was through Notepad++ search and replace dialog on Windows. Now I realized that it doesn't seem so easy to match patterns across lines using other tools. In Notepad++ I simply use \n.

Using Perl to process regular expressions at the command line, I have a relatively easy time if I use the "slurp mode". I can use a line like

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/pattern/replace-text/' foo.txt
```

and "pattern" can have as many \n as I need.

What alternatives do I have for Linux command line with which I can use my regexes containing (\r)\n? Matching patterns in text spanning lines is particularly important to me.

Comment: Perl should accept `\n` in the pattern, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Perl Compatible Regular Expressions installed, take a look at pcregrep.  (If you have pcre2 installed, it would be pcre2grep.)  Anyway, if the manual pages are also installed, check out the dash-M (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M) option, which will allow you to match over multiple lines.  If you don't have the man pages installed, you can go to pcre-dot-org and all the documentation is there.

A couple examples follow, but first, the input file:

```
$ cat malt
this is foo
bar baz

this is foo'd up
beyond all barz

this is foo
        bar

foo
  bar

blah blah foobar blah
```

Now, a regex matching newline, as in your example:

```
$ pcregrep -M 'foo\nbar' malt
this is foo
bar baz
```

For the following, I'll use dash-n option (same as grep:  print line number) to make it more obvious how many matches there were, and on what line the first part of the match occurred.  Here, I'm trying to match "foo" followed by a single newline, zero-or-more whitespaces (i.e., optional), then "bar":

```
$ pcregrep -nM 'foo\n\s*bar' malt
1:this is foo
bar baz
7:this is foo
        bar
10:foo
  bar
```

This time (with optional whitespace), we matched three times, starting on Line 1, 7, and 10 (respectively).  Another consideration is if you want to have the dot (FULL STOP) match line break or not.  This can be done with `(?s)` mode modifier, for example:

```
$ pcregrep -nM '(?s:foo.*bar)' malt
1:this is foo
bar baz

this is foo'd up
beyond all barz

this is foo
        bar

foo
  bar

blah blah foobar blah
```

Just be sure you read up on "greedy" versus "lazy" match modes.  Notice the above matched a single time, starting with the "foo" on Line 1: all the way to the **last bar** on the file.  The difference is significant when compared to how "lazy" consumption works--which we can do using the the `?` quantification behavior modifier like so:

```
$ pcregrep -nM '(?s:foo.*?bar)' malt
1:this is foo
bar baz
4:this is foo'd up
beyond all barz
7:this is foo
        bar
10:foo
  bar
13:blah blah foobar blah
```

The latter is identical expression to the former, only with the '?' Lazy behavior modifier.

Comment: Good! Thank you for your detailed post and general advices. From what I've gathered so far, I seems it doesn't get easier than this. Thank you.